# GWT compiler [ERROR] Line: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Foo

Tags: java, gwt, ant

I've started to get a wierd error when Im compiling my GWT. It only happens sometime.

```
 [java] [ERROR] Line 62: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to SomeClass
```

and Line 62 in the file looks like this

```
for (SomeClass ans : someAutobeanInterface.getSomeClasses()) {
```

And someAutobeanInterface.getSomeClasses()

```
List<SomeClass> getSomeClasses();
```

someAutobeanInterface is a GWT AutoBean interface.

I'm using gwt version 2.5.0

I use ant to compile the gwt.

```
<target name="fetch-gwt-dev">
    <echo>Setting up GWT-dependencies</echo>

    <artifact:dependencies filesetId="gwt-dev.dependencies.classpath">
        <dependency groupId="com.google.gwt" artifactId="gwt-dev" version="2.5.0" />
        <dependency groupId="com.bradrydzewski" artifactId="gwt-cal" version="0.9.3.1" />
        <dependency groupId="com.google.gwt.google-apis" artifactId="gwt-visualization" version="1.0.2" />
    </artifact:dependencies>

    <artifact:dependencies filesetId="gwt-user.dependencies.classpath">
        <dependency groupId="com.google.gwt" artifactId="gwt-user" version="2.5.0" />
        <dependency groupId="javax.validation" artifactId="validation-api" version="1.0.0.GA" classifier="sources" />
    </artifact:dependencies>
</target>

<macrodef name="compilegwtappfast" >
    <!-- XXX This macro is kind of strange since it depends on the target fetch-gwt-dev to have been run -->

    <attribute name="package" />
    <attribute name="fakepackage" />
    <attribute name="outputdir" />
    <!-- The number of workers -->
    <attribute name="numberOfWorkers" />
    <!-- If the app needs some additional entry on the classpath (such as GWT-Widgets, that should be added here) -->
    <element name="additional-classpath" optional="true" />

    <sequential>
        <echo>Compiling GWT app @{package} and putting it in @{outputdir}</echo>
        <echo>Compiling package: @{fakePackage}</echo>

        <!-- This directory isn't in SVN so it's not a problem if it doesn't exist -->
        <delete description="Cleaning compiler output directory" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="@{outputdir}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </delete>

        <java fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler" failonerror="true">
            <classpath>
                <fileset refid="gwt-user.dependencies.classpath" />
                <fileset refid="gwt-dev.dependencies.classpath" />
                <filelist dir="${basedir}">
                    <file name="src/main/java/" />
                </filelist>
            </classpath>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
            <arg line="-localWorkers @{numberOfWorkers}" />
            <arg line="-war @{outputdir}"/>
            <arg value="@{fakepackage}" />
        </java>

        <copy todir="@{outputdir}" description="Move the compiler-output to it's right location" failonerror="true">
            <fileset dir="@{outputdir}/@{package}/">
                <include name="**" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <delete dir="@{outputdir}/@{package}">
        </delete>
    <tstamp>
        <format property="DONE_COMPILING" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>  
    </tstamp>  
    <echo>Done compiling GWT-app: ${DONE_COMPILING}</echo>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="compile-gwt" depends="fetch-gwt-dev">
    <compilegwtapp package="my.gwt.package" outputdir="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/mygwt/" numberOfWorkers="4"/>
</target>
```

Anyone that has any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please share code of method `getSomeClasses()` to make it clear that what have you returned.

Comment: It's only an interface. See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean for more information about GWTs AutoBean.

Answer (score 0):

It may be smth wrong with Java compiler compliance settings in eclipse. They probably set up to not allow 1.5+ syntax.